# $injector:modulerr Injecting Custom Module Into Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this main application called dashboard and I want to inject a custom made module called core.

I keep getting this injection error and I have no idea why. I am following a template that my co-worker has and it is pretty much word for word so I do not know why it is not working for me.

app.js

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    var dependencies = [
        'ngRoute',
        'core' 

    ]; // all our modules  

    angular.module('dashboard', dependencies).config(Config); //.config(Config); 

    Config.$inject = ['$locationProvider'];

    function Config($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); 

    }   

    angular.element(document).ready(function(){

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['dashboard']); 


    });

})();
```

layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/javascripts/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' /> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flud-container">
            {{{body}}}
    </div>
  </body>

    <!-- JS  Libraries -->   
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>   
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script> 
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/lib/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js'></script> 

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/modules/core/core.client.module.js'></script>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/modules/core/config/core.client.routes.js'></script>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/app.js'></script>  
</html>
```

core.client.module.js

```
(function(){

    'use strict'; 

//  var dependencies = [ 


//  ]; 

    angular.module('core', []);

    angular.module('core').run(intialize);

    initialize.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location']; 

    function intitialize($rootScope, $location){

        //initialize module's variables here 

    }  




});
```

console error:

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=dashboard&p1=Error%…(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A463)
```

Comment: from the stacktrace it's unclear which modile is raising the error. can you try to disable one by one 'core.client.module.js and 'core.client.routes.js' to see which works and which still fails ?

Comment: you missed to execute `core.client.module.js` function, it should `(function(){ ...........})()`, basically you need to call function to get invoked it immediately

Comment: @shershen I did that and it's forsure core cause ngRoute works fine.

Comment: @PankajParkar omg! your right I totally forgot () that at the end to invoke! thanks! cant believe i missed that hahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were using `IIFE` pattern for restricting the scope of code, you should invoke function of `core.client.module.js` immediately to `core` module get available.

**core.client.module.js**

```
(function(){ 

   //---- code here-----//

})(); //<---invoke the function
```